# formula for the sextic polynomial

Tags: polynomials

you can solve quantic equations by elliptic functions,
but that doesn't work for the sextic polynomials,
how to solve the general sextic polynomial, for example, $x^6-12x^5+4x^4+4x^3+3x^2+12x-12=0$?

note: I know how to solve the equation: $x^n+x+t=0$
the formula is easy with experience, knowledge and patience 
however what about the general formula?
is there a way to reduce it to the equation $x^n+x+t$?
if so, how?

edit: when I say x^n+x+t
I mean x^6+x+t and t is some constant ( number ) 
where n is 6

Comment: I suppose you mean *quintic* equations, in your first sentence?

Comment: Jordan has shown all algebraic equations can be solved by use of modular functions. Thomae has worked out a formula for that. Later Umemura has expressed these modular functions in higher genus theta functions. The solution of $x^N + x + t$ is known as a Bring radical and can be expressed as a finite series of hypergeometric functions.
Look at wiki entry of [Thomae's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_formula), [Bring radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical) and refs there for more info.

Comment: $x^6-12 x^5+4 x^4+4 x^3+3 x^2+12 x-12=(x-1) \left(x^5-11 x^4-7 x^3-3 x^2+12\right)$ so the problem is about solving $$x^5-11 x^4-7 x^3-3 x^2+12=0$$